# jquery bind to a trigger already executed

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where a code sometimes is executed before another code is finished. So I thought that I use trigger to handle this. However the bind is executed only when the trigger event is executed after the bind is attached.

```
$(document).trigger('myevent');
$(document).on('myevent', function() { console.log('my event is called'); });
```

This is just to show the workflow. (The two lines are not in the same function: the first line is from an ajax call and the second is from a ready event) Sometimes the first line is executed before the second and sometimes they execute in the expected way (the second line and then the first line).

How can I attach to past triggers? Or how can I cover both cases?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can't travel back in time to add a handler to an event that already happened.

Comment: You need to get your event binding code to run first.

Comment: But that is exactly what I am asking. How to make the event binding to be executed first in the above conditions: the trigger is done from an ajax call and the second is an jquery ready event. Also the ajax call is also done directly (not in a jquery ready) and is executed before the jquery code

Comment: You need to change the order that scripts are loaded, so your script is loaded first. Since you're adding the event listener to `document` you don't need to wait for `$(document).ready()`.